# Photo recovery from a MotoX phone with black screen

Tags: moto-x

I have a MotoX (1st Gen) phone. A few days back my display went black and I am not able to see anything once the phone boots. The notifications are getting displayed on the locked screen, but when I am trying to unlock, the screen is getting black again. The voice command is responding sometimes, but that's about it. I have cleared the cache partition, but that did not help either. Please tell me some way to recover the photos/videos in my mobile.

Comment: Though your screen is not physically broken – not being able to interact with it makes it pretty close in dealing with the issue, so please take a look at our [broken-screen tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info), which has a few hints and links on data recovery in comparable situations.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone still works, so you got lucky.

Plug the device into a PC/Mac and navigate the phone's file directory. Look for the root folder "DCIM". All of your videos and photos should be in there.

Comment: I had already tried connecting my phone to laptop using USB cable. But my laptop is not detecting anything. Only the phone is charging.

Comment: And the device works besides the screen being broken? That's really weird.

Comment: Duh. Do you know where you have to tap to enter your password? You need to get past your lockscreen before the computer will see any files.

Comment: The phone is 10% functional at best. Only the booting and charging are taking place properly. It is showing the notifications and recognising the voice commands sometimes. Only possible solution for recovery that I have found is using OTG cable and use a screen with HDMI input support to turn on USB debugging. But that solution is quite expensive. It would be great if I can get an alternative solution.

Answer (score -2):

I think this will work. 
just go to this website.

https://www.fonelab.com/resource/moto-x-data-recovery-recover-videos-from-moto-x.html

just download the app.

app is only for apple and windows.
this app recovers media.

Comment: Their website doesn't have a physical location for the company, not even a country, and they hide their identity in the domain registration. I wouldn't buy anything from these people or run their software on my computer.

Comment: I agree with Dan. Looking at the software signature it turns out that this product is from "RayShare Co,.Ltd", a software publisher located in Beijing, China (according to some data I found on the net).